# Combining text files name

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a list.

```
List<string> slots = HexStringToGenerateFiles(weaponStorageEntity.Slot);
```

I’m retrieving the list using foreach loop and did some conversion at the same time.

```
string slotnumber = "";
string ibuttonslot = "";
foreach (string slot in slots)
{
 slotnumber += slot;
 ibuttonslot = ByteOperation.ReverseString((Convert.ToString(1 << ((Int32.Parse(slotnumber)) - 1), 2).PadLeft(16, '0')));
}
```

Then, save the output as a name of a textfile.

```
  CreateFile(String.Format("{0}\\B_{1:X16}.TXT",
                                   userDir,
                                   ibuttonslot,
                                   ));
```

If I have 3 slots, then my output will have 3 textfiles. However, I would like it to combine it be one textfile only. My output is something as shown below.

> B_10000000.TXT
>
> B_01000000.TXT
>
> B_00100000.TXT

My desired output is

> B_11100000.TXT

Comment: So the Problem is in Merging the file or naming the file? or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your slots numbered just as "1", "2", "3", ... and want to produce a name of the file that would represent "1" in a corresponding slot - so for "1 3" it would be 10100000... then you can use something like this:

```
var slots = new[] { "1" };
var number = 0; 
foreach (var s in slots)
{
    int slotNumber;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(s, out slotNumber)) continue;

    var slot = (int)Math.Pow(2, slotNumber - 1);
    number |= slot;
}

var fileName = Convert.ToString(number, 2).PadLeft(16, '0');
Console.WriteLine(fileName); //output is 0000000000000101
```

And then revert this string (in your code it is ByteOperation.ReverseString).

Comment: I just found out that if none of the slots were chosen. meaning when 
var slots = new[ ]{" "}; there will be error.

Comment: Updated the answer with TryParse

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine both file's text then you can use `File.ReadAllLines(string)` method and combine the output like

```
        List<string> contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(firstfile).ToList();
        contents.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(secondfile));
```

Comment: But in your comment you said content ...??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for combining names:

```
string in1 = "B_10000000.TXT";
string in2 = "B_01000000.TXT";
string in3 = "B_00100000.TXT";
char[] charsInName = in1.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charsInName.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (charsInName[i] != in2[i] && charsInName[i] != in3[i])
        charsInName[i] = charsInName[i];
    else if (charsInName[i] != in2[i])
        charsInName[i] = in2[i];
    else if (charsInName[i] != in3[i])
        charsInName[i] = in3[i];
}
string outPutName = String.Join("", charsInName);// will be B_11100000.TXT
```

Or can use LINQ:

```
var result = in1.Select(
    (x, y) => x != in2[y] && x != in3[y] ? x :
    x != in2[y] ? in2[y] : 
    x != in3[y] ? in3[y] : x);
string outPutName = String.Join("", result);
```